# AgensGraph extension not found in PostgreSQL and cypher queries not working

Tags: apache-age

I'm trying to work with AgensGraph extension in PostgreSQL, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. When I run the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
     MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person)
     WHERE a.name = 'Node A' AND b.name = 'Node B'
     CREATE (a)-[e:RELTYPE {name:a.name + '<->' + b.name}]->(b)
     RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);

SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
     RETURN to_char(to_timestamp(timestamp() / 1000), 'Month DD, YYYY, HH:MI:SS')
$$) as (t agtype);
```

I get the following errors respectively:

```
ERROR:  function ag_catalog.age_to_timestamp(agtype) does not exist
LINE 3: RETURN to_char(to_timestamp(timestamp() / 1000), 'Month DD, ...
```

```
ERROR:  function cypher(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: FROM cypher('graph', $$
```

When I check if AgensGraph is installed by running **`SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'agensgraph';`**, I get no rows.I also tried to load the extension by running **`LOAD 'agensgraph';`**, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "agensgraph": No such file or directory
What am I missing here? How can I properly install and use AgensGraph in PostgreSQL?
```

---

I'm trying to use the **`timestamp()`** function in my PostgreSQL database, but I'm getting an error message when I try to access it.I'm not sure why this error is happening, since **`timestamp()`** is a built-in function in PostgreSQL. What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

Also, I'm trying to use the AgensGraph extension in my database, but it doesn't seem to be installed. When I run **`SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'agensgraph';`**, I get no rows returned. And when I try to load the extension with **`LOAD 'agensgraph';`**, I get an error saying that the file could not be found.

What could be causing these issues and how can I resolve them?

Answer (score 1):

The error in the timestamp() part as `to_timestamp()` is not a valid cypher Function. For more details regarding the timestamp() function, you can check this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783422/date-and-time-functions-in-apache-age-database/75783600#75783600).

For installation of AgensGraph you can follow [Bitnine guide](https://bitnine.net/documentations/quick-guide-2-0.html?ckattempt=1#installation)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no `to_timestamp` function in AGE currently. Secondly, make sure the extension is installed properly. You can check the list of installed extensions by typing the following in psql:

```
postgres=# \dx
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 age     | 1.1.0   | ag_catalog | AGE database extension
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
```

Lastly, make sure your path is SET correctly. The `cypher` function is not found because it is not native to postgres and must be looked up inside the `ag_catalog` schema.

```
SET search_path = ag_catalog, "$user", public;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is stored in a table `nodes` with a column `data` that contains the node properties, the exact SQL statement generated from the AGE query will be:

```
SELECT data FROM nodes;
```

This will retrieve all rows from `nodes` table and return the properties from the `data` colum.